# Powershell script to create a Service Bus in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, service

I'm looking for help with a powershell script to create a service bus (if it doesn't already exits) under the current subscription, create Send and Listen queues under that service bus and a SAS key under each queue. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at Microsoft docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.servicebus/v0.0.2/azurerm.servicebus

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Azure and PowerShell SDK documentation. Also, there are some good ARM examples within the [Azure QuickStart Templates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/) too.

One thing to beware of is that for a long time only a limited amount of administration of the Azure Service Bus has been supported with PowerShell. If you can't find how to do something with the cmdlets in the documentation, then you may need to write some simple C# code using the Azure Service Bus SDK APIs instead. I've run into this in the past when I needed to manage and create Azure Service Bus Topics with Subscriptions using SQL Filters.